# Dealing with large amount of data (around 400 million records)

Tags: mysql, database, networking, bigdata

I have a big data set (a table) stored a user id field, date field, country field (e.g. USA, FRA, etc), and other fields

```
| User ID   |    Date    |  Country  | Other Fields ... |
|-----------|------------|-----------|------------------|
| 1         | 2013-2-1   |    USA    |    ...           |
| 2         | 2013-2-1   |    FRA    |    ...           |
| 3         | 2013-2-2   |    GBK    |    ...           |
```

The data structure is simple, and I want to pass the date, country, and possibly other fields, 
and query the answer.

The problem is that there are around **400 millions** of records, if I use ordinary db such as MySQL, the speed will become extremely slow.

Currently no specific database, programming languages, or methodology are required, any tools that possible to make it works are okay, such as MySQL, Redis, Mongo etc, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the query type, splitting into multiple tables may help (for cases when it is possible to determine in advance which sub-tables contain the required rows).

This is not a very clean design but further splitting into multiple database servers (may also help) is even more complex.